# Finetune mBART on pre-train tasks using HuggingFace

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model, fine-tuning

I would like to finetune `facebook/mbart-large-cc25` on my data using pre-training tasks, in particular Masked Language Modeling (MLM).

How can I do that in HuggingFace?

Edit: rewrote the question for the sake of clarity

Comment: I think for the most part you can simply follow the existing Q&A scripts (e.g., [these ones](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch/question-answering)) and substitute in MBart. If you do need specific help, please make sure your post only includes *a single question*, to ensure answers are consistent.

Comment: I rewrote the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing everything in HuggingFace, fine-tuning a model on pre-training tasks (assuming that pre-training task is provided in Huggingface) is pretty much the same for most models. What tasks are you interested in fine-tuning mBART on?

Hugginface provides extensive documentation for several fine-tuning tasks. For instance the links provided below will help you fine tune HF models for Language modelling, MNLI, SQuAD etc.  https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.0.0/examples.html and https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html

Comment: Please note that the link to the examples is *extremely* outdated. Please refer to this one instead (latest version): https://huggingface.co/transformers/master/examples.html

Comment: I would like to do MLM using HF, but I didn't find any tutorial

Comment: This link should help : https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch/language-modeling

The script run_mlm.py can be used for finetuning your HF model.

Comment: mBART is not supported according to the comment at line 19 https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/62832c962f85b5a554ebf8b930d13b76b9028a8d/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_mlm.py#L19